# Изменение данных в поле input по нажатию клавиши

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

При нажатии на клавишу цифры 1 эта цифра должна отображаться в поле input, но ничего не работает.

```js
var fieldNum = document.getElementById('fieldNum').value;
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    if(event.keyCode === 97) {
    fieldNum = '1';
  }
})
```

```css
.field {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  //border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 250px auto 10px;

}
.num {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  //border: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num:hover {
  background: #9fbfdf;
}
input {
  margin-left: 43%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="num" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="num" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="num" id="three">3</div>
  <div class="num" id="four">4</div>
  <div class="num" id="five">5</div>
  <div class="num" id="six">6</div>
  <div class="num" id="seven">7</div>
  <div class="num" id="eight">8</div>
  <div class="num" id="nine">9</div>
  <div class="num" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="num" id="plus">+</div>
  <div class="num" id="minus">-</div>
  <div class="num" id="divide">/</div>
  <div class="num" id="multiply">*</div>
  <div class="num" id="equal">=</div>
</div>
<input id="fieldNum" type="text" onkeydown="this.nextSibling.innerHTML = event.keyCode" disabled><b></b>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых единица имеет код `49` (на нумпаде должна быть `97`, но там тоже приходит `49`), а во-вторых присвоить значение для `value` нужно иначе (в вашем случае меняется значение переменной, а не значение в поле), вот рабочий пример вашего примера кода:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function() {

  // вывести в консоль значнеие кода клавиши
  // console.log(event.keyCode); // раскомментировать при надобности

  if (event.keyCode == 49) { // клавиша '1' - имеет код '49'
    document.getElementById('fieldNum').value = '1'; // поменяем значение
  }
})
```

```css
.field {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  //border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 250px auto 10px;
}

.num {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  //border: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num:hover {
  background: #9fbfdf;
}

input {
  margin-left: 43%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="num" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="num" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="num" id="three">3</div>
  <div class="num" id="four">4</div>
  <div class="num" id="five">5</div>
  <div class="num" id="six">6</div>
  <div class="num" id="seven">7</div>
  <div class="num" id="eight">8</div>
  <div class="num" id="nine">9</div>
  <div class="num" id="zero">0</div>
  <div class="num" id="plus">+</div>
  <div class="num" id="minus">-</div>
  <div class="num" id="divide">/</div>
  <div class="num" id="multiply">*</div>
  <div class="num" id="equal">=</div>
</div>
<input id="fieldNum" type="text" onkeydown="this.nextSibling.innerHTML = event.keyCode" disabled><b></b>
```

Чтобы появился результат - необходимо, чтобы область сниппета была активной. Для этого достаточно кликнуть мышкой внутри выполненного сниппета, чтобы JS-код сниппета перехватывал нажатия клавиш события `keypress`.

Comment: Вы уверены что пример рабочий? Ничего не происходит при нажатии.

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев ага, уверен. Чтобы работало - нужно кликнуть в область результата, а потом жать клавишу один (область результата - имеется в виду в сниппете)